# How to compare species communities between two years?

Tags: similarities, ecology

I would like to compare the data of a community of species between two years. I used to compare communities based on different levels of a factor (for example, a treatment). The case of a treatment is easy because each site has a corresponding level of the treatment.

However, if the factor is a year, we face a paired design with each site sampled twice. In this case I cannot just assign a year to a site and, therefore, I do not know which method I should apply to analyse community differences between two years.

Comment: What about the community of species are you comparing?  A diversity index, species richness, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's true that my context is not that clear. I have a sites (rows) x species (columns) matrix with each entry corresponding to the abundance of the species in the site. I would like to investigate the changes in species composition between two years. In the case of a treatment I use the function "adonis" in R for comparing the variance in species composition between the different levels of the treatment. However I don't think that I can do the same for a paired design.

Comment: Is this the same question that has been posted in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_method_to_analyze_change_in_species_composition_over_three_years_in_different_sites)? If so you could edit this question to add the details you mentioned in RG, it'd make it easier to answer it.